# Where do I find the password for this door at the top of the ship? - [Chippin'in job]

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

During the **Chippin'in** job, at the top of the ship (opposite side where you confronted the last guy with Rogue as shown in the picture), there is a door with a password to open it.
[image: door with password]

I checked computers, containers, and shards all around and couldn't find the password.

Does anyone know where the code is?

[image: pad with digits to enter the password]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell that code isn't findable. You can either try to hack that terminal to open it, but then you don't have access to the weapon case inside the room, but there is still other stuff to loot in there.

To gain full access to the room without hacking or a code you need to finish the game.

> In the final mission "Nocturne OP55N1" you'll have to fight Adam Smasher and get his shard. With that you're able to open that door when you entered the open world after the credits and have access to the weapon crate containing the crafting spec of the legendary iconic weapon ["Ba Xing Chong"](https://cyberpunk2077.wiki.fextralife.com/Ba+Xing+Chong).